# Google Sheets: count occurrences of a string in different columns

Tags: google-sheets

```
ColA        ColB    ColC    ColD    ColE
Date        ID1     ID2     ID3     ID4
1/12/2016   79858   1219        
1/15/2016   761     159473      
1/19/2016   107597  36204       
1/19/2016   109374  93360       
1/19/2016           2040        
1/19/2016   115902  83366   12617   
1/19/2016           7902    
1/19/2016   2040    34312       
1/19/2016   111954          
1/19/2016   2040    116886      
1/20/2016   90553   76985       
1/20/2016   85454   15933       
1/20/2016   88148           
1/20/2016   115902  35453   93364   
1/20/2016           58459   
1/20/2016   49432   112242  75566   154497
1/22/2016   101672  58459       
1/22/2016               
1/25/2016   1211    2040    39552   
1/25/2016           752
```

I'm trying to count the number of times an ID is present in the range ColB:ColE if Date is between a timeframe.

With `=COUNTIF(B2:E,"79858")` I can count the number of times a specific ID appears in all the columns with the IDs, but I can't add the date in a `COUNTIFS` function because the size of the arrays would be different:

```
=COUNTIFS(D2:H,"79858",A2:A,">=19/01/2016",A2:A,"<22/01/2016")

Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size.
```

Right now `=COUNTIFS(D2:D,"79858",A2:A,">=19/01/2016",A2:A,"<22/01/2016")+COUNTIFS(E2:E,"79858",A2:A,">=19/01/2016",A2:A,"<22/01/2016")+COUNTIFS(F2:F,"79858",A2:A,">=19/01/2016",A2:A,"<22/01/2016")+COUNTIFS(G2:G,"79858",A2:A,">=19/01/2016",A2:A,"<22/01/2016")+COUNTIFS(H2:H,"79858",A2:A,">=19/01/2016",A2:A,"<22/01/2016")` is working, but it's really resource-heavy.. is there a less resource-heavy (and elegant) way? Like an ARRAYFORMULA..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the numbers are formatted (as 'text' or as 'numbers')

try:

```
=COUNTIF(filter(B2:E, A2:A>date(2016, 1, 19), A2:A<date(2016, 1, 22)), 79858)
```

or

```
=COUNTIF(filter(B2:E, A2:A>date(2016, 1, 19), A2:A<date(2016, 1, 22)), "79858")
```

and see if that works ?

Comment: Last thing. If I want to use this formula from another document.. how could I reference those cells? I tried with `COUNTIF(filter(IMPORTRANGE("XXXXX","'Sheet'!B2:E"), IMPORTRANGE("XXXXX","'Sheet'!A2:A")>date(2016, 1, 19), IMPORTRANGE("XXXXX","'Sheet'!A2:A")<date(2016, 1, 22)), 79858)` but it results 0 (instead if I use the formula inside the same doc as the IDs it works).

Comment: Ignore, it works. It needed a few seconds to import and count. :)